# Problem with using procedure parameter inside IF statement

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a Postgres procedure for a table with an optional TRUNCATE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE db.refresh_table(complete_refresh boolean DEFAULT false)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$

DECLARE
    PREVIOUS_DAY TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN
    PREVIOUS_DAY := DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY');

    IF complete_refresh THEN
        TRUNCATE TABLE db.table;
    END IF;

    ... other statements

END;

$procedure$;
```

It complains though with `ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"`

I tried another way:

```
IF complete_refresh=true THEN
```

The result is the same. What is correct way of using the boolean parameter as condition in an IF statement?

Comment: alternative use 0 and 1 rather!

Comment: Are you sure the previous statement is terminated correctly (with a semicolon)? Please provide a [mcve], or the actual code if necessary

Comment: @Bergi I added the code lines before the IF

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/ant5g1nG)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem either. What client are you using to create the procedure? My suspicion is that there is some sort of hidden character getting in the way.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Oh could be, need to find it.

Comment: What client are you using to create the function?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It's through Flyway Migration (Redgate), triggered by an Airflow DAG. The error shown is  a log on Airflow task.

Answer (score 0):

You need `BEGIN`. This works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE refresh_table(complete_refresh boolean DEFAULT false)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
begin
    IF complete_refresh THEN
        TRUNCATE TABLE xxx;
    END IF;
end; 

$procedure$;
```

Comment: Sorry, I have that BEGIN. I just forgot to add in the code.

Comment: Can you run the code which I provided? Does it also fail for you?